# how to avoid duplicate retrofit 2 calls when a condition is met using viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, retrofit2

Hello amazing programmers of stack overflow, I'm trying to make a network request when a condition is met on viewpager.AddOnPageChangeListner using retrofit2, and showing progress dialog while it fetches the data, the problem is when swiping across the screen sometimes, the same network request is triggered twice resulting in duplicate data and sometimes it just works fine, what changes can i make to avoid duplicate network request.

```
 mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


                if (imageUrls.size() - 1 == position & !nextCursor.equals("") & Util.isNetworkAvailable()) {

                    if (mResources != null){
                        mResources.clear();
                    }

                     // retrofit network request method
                        fetchImages(category, nextCursor);

                }

                if ((imageUrls.size() - 1 == position) & (Util.isNetworkAvailable() == false)) {


                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet  " + imageUrls.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
```

Below is the retrofit request method declaration

```
private void fetchImages(final String mCategory, final String mNextCursor) {

    dialog.show();

    call = ApiUtils.getImageService().getImageResource(mCategory, mNextCursor);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ImageResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ImageResponse> call, Response<ImageResponse> response) {

            imageResponse = response.body();

            if (imageResponse.getResources() != null) {

                mResources = imageResponse.getResources();

                for (int i = 0; i < mResources.size(); i++) {

                     String imageUrl = mResources.get(i).getUrl();

                     String imageName = mResources.get(i).getPublicId();


                    Log.i("retrofitImageUrl",imageName);

                    imageUrls.add(imageUrl);
                    imageNames.add(imageName);

                }

                if (imageResponse.getNextCursor() != null) {
                    nextCursor = imageResponse.getNextCursor();


                } else {
                    nextCursor = "";
                }

                    imageInfo = ImageInfo.getInstance();

                    imageInfo.setImageUrls(imageUrls);
                    imageInfo.setPublicImageId(imageNames);
                    imageInfo.setNextcursor(nextCursor);
                    imageInfo.setCategoryType(mCategory);


                String jSon = gson.toJson(imageInfo);
                editor.putString("imageInfo",jSon);
                editor.commit();

                if (mPagerAdapter == null) {

                    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mContext);

                    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

                    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else {
                    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No valid data was returned, please try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            dialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ImageResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error:something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

I was able to fix the issue by using Async task and change retrofit network request type to synchronous  by adding following if condition

```
 if (urls.size() - 1 == position & !nextCursor.equals("") & Util.isNetworkAvailable()) {

                mResources.clear();

                if ((imageDownloadAsyncTask.getStatus() != Status.RUNNING)&(imageDownloadAsyncTask.getStatus() != Status.PENDING)) {
                    asyncTask(category);
                }

            }
```

I'd really like to use retrofit async call rather than separate async task but how do i avoid duplicate calls using retrofit ? I couldn't find call.pending or call.running method in retrofit. Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Comment: You should have some timestamp in backend which will change if anyupdate is there in the backend data. When you first load data you should  save timestamp locally and next time compare it to backend value and make fetch image call based on changes..

Answer (score 0):

In you case I think you need to implement some kind image cache system. Basically, if you already have downloaded an image you don't make a new call to download again the image. Plus you will need some kind flag to know if you are currently downloading a image or not.

I would suggest you to use Picasso, Glide or ImageDownloader that already provide all of this.